# Ember.Select not working?

Tags: ember.js

I'm working off of sample code from http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html and it doesn't appear to be working? I get this error:

`Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed names ember.js:394
Uncaught TypeError: Object names has no method 'addArrayObserver'`

Here's my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/kogav/1/

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="names"}}
```

See http://jsbin.com/gocel/1/

Comment: Thanks chopper, this is the 2nd time I've run into what I'm assuming is deprecated samples from their guides/api pages. Think I'll fork those pages and fix! Can't upvote yet, but when will do so when able to.